# How to represent hierarchical data in select input?

Tags: html, css

I am not asking how to generate it, but rather how to format it. Is there any set of characters that is meant for that purpose? My intuitive approach was to have the options with the following values:

```
master
    |-- foo 1
    |-- foo 2
        |-- bar 1
```

Comment: would you prefer jQuery?

Comment: @codingbiz My question seems to be misunderstood. I don't want to make this a fancy AJAX chain-select or represent data in a nested unordered list. I simply want to present the tree in HTML `select` input. I am asking what is the most appropriate way to do that.

Comment: It doesn't exist in html. The best answer for html is already posted by @Ana

Comment: @Guy: we understand that, what the (correct) answers and comments are telling you is that this *isn't possible*. An `optgroup` can indent a little, but they can't be nested, so a `select` can only offer two levels of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The box drawing characters are meant for purposes like this, more or less. At the minimum, you would use U+251C BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND RIGHT “├” and U+2500 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL“─”. For example,

```
<select>
<option>master
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x251c;&#x2500; foo 1
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x251c;&#x2500; foo 2
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x251c;&#x2500; bar 1
</select>
```

However, it will be difficult to get the symbols aligned well. Using no-break spaces as above is a coarse tool, and most importantly, character widths vary—so you might consider using a CSS rule like

```
 select, option { font-family: Consolas, monospace }
```

to get more predictable rendering.

Comment: That's the answer. Though, it would be nice if you could advise more suitable characters.

Comment: List of "suitable characters" https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/HTMLandASCIItableC1.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it with a select element and you don't need more than two levels, then you could use [**`optgroup`**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/optgroup).

CSS styling is limited. As far as I know, for the `select` itself you can change things like `color`, `background`, `border`, `font`, `text-align`.

For `optgroup` and `option`, you can change... well, the same things. You can also style the selected option differently using `[selected] {/*styles*/}`. You cannot change `padding` or `margin`... things like that. And trying to nest `optgroup`s doesn't work either.

What you can do: you can style different `optgroup`s and `option`s differently (using classes, nth-child, a attribute selectors).

[**Demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3159673)

If you need a lot of levels, then perhaps it would be better to use nested lists.

```
<ul>
    <li>master
        <ul>
            <li>foo 1</li>
            <li>foo 2
                <ul>
                    <li>bar 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For the sake of other who refer to this question, this is about infinite number of levels. Though, what's exactly a nested list?

Comment: Nested list is that what also Alien has mentioned above: `<ul> <li> Master <ul> <li> foo1 </li> <li> foo2 <ul> <li> bar1 </li> </ul> </li> </ul>` and you can stylize it with `ul {list-style: none;}`

Comment: This question is specifically about how to format select input options.

Comment: @Ana, I am referring more to the clever Unicode character trickery than CSS.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to use javascript or jQuery to manipulate the `select` list here is my solution

```
<select name="hierarchies">
<option class="level_1">Computer Science</option>
   <option class="level_2">Java</option>
      <option class="level_3">Martin Fowler</option>
      <option class="level_3">Ian Galloway</option>
<option class="level_1">Computer Engr</option>
   <option class="level_2">C#</option>
      <option class="level_3">John Skeet</option>
      <option class="level_3">Phil Haack</option>
      <option class="level_3">Marc Garvel</option>
<option class="level_1">C</option>
</select>
```

then use jQuery or JavaScript to reformat the content based on the level

```
$(document).ready(
 function(){

   $('.level_2').each(
        function(){
            $(this).text('------'+$(this).text());
        }
   );

   $('.level_3').each(
        function(){
            $(this).text('---------'+$(this).text());
        }
   );

  }
);
```

Resulting screen

[image]